# Retrofit2, how to convert response to base class?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have base class for my responses. This class gets called when there is a problem (such as authentications problem).

```
public class DefaultResponse
{
    private transient Integer status;
    private String            property;
    private String            message;
    private String            developerMessage;
    protected String          code;

    public void setResponse(final Response response)
    {
        if (this.status != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (response != null)
        {
            try
            {
                final Object obj = response.body();
                if (obj != null && obj instanceof DefaultResponse)
                {
                    this.status = response.code();
                    this.message = ((DefaultResponse) obj).message;
                    this.developerMessage = ((DefaultResponse) obj).developerMessage;
                    this.property = ((DefaultResponse) obj).property;
                    this.code = ((DefaultResponse) obj).code;
                }
            }
            catch (final Exception ignored)
            {

            }
        }
    }

...
}
```

The rest of Responses are extending this class.

```
public class FeatureResponse extends DefaultResponse 
{
    // Implementation
}
```

This is the method I'm using to call the API in order to get Features.

```
    public void getFeatures(final Location location)
    {
        Call<FeatureResponse> call = mService.getPassengerFeatures(location);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<FeatureResponse>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FeatureResponse> call, Response<FeatureResponse> response)
            {
                Logger.debug("Test", "Instance of response: " + response.getClass());

                FeatureResponse featureResponse = new FeatureResponse();

                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    //...
                }

                featureResponse.setResponse(response);
                EventBus.post(featureResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FeatureResponse> call, Throwable t)
            {
                Logger.error(TAG, "getPassengerFeatures.onFailure(), msg: " + t.getMessage());

                FeatureResponse featureResponse = new FeatureResponse();
                featureResponse.setFailure(t);
                EventBus.post(featureResponse);
            }
        });
    }
```

When I send the request, this is my server response:

```
{"status":403,"code":4030,"property":"","message":"Unauthorized access","developerMessage":"Unauthorized access"}
```

Therefore, `onResponse` gets called, new object of `FeatureResponse` gets created and `featureResponse.setResponse(response);` gets called. As you see in above code I'm trying to get its HTTP status code. However, the problem is `if (obj != null && obj instanceof DefaultResponse)` is always `false` as `response` is Instance of class retrofit2.Response.

Is it possible to convert `Response` to `DefaultResponse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i am getting error such as 401 , 400 am using this way with `Gson` :

```
if (response.code() == 400) 
{
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
   MyPojoError myPojoError=new MyPojoError ();
   try {
         myPojoError= gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(),MyPojoError .class);
        } catch (IOException e) {  // handle failure to read error   }

}
```

Also you need annotations when converting response to `Pojo` with `Gson` :

```
public class MyPojoError {

@SerializedName("error")
@Expose
private String error;
@SerializedName("error_description")
@Expose
private String errorDescription;

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The error
 */
public String getError() {
    return error;
}

/**
 *
 * @param error
 * The error
 */
public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The errorDescription
 */
public String getErrorDescription() {
    return errorDescription;
}

/**
 *
 * @param errorDescription
 * The error_description
 */
public void setErrorDescription(String errorDescription) {
    this.errorDescription = errorDescription;
}

}
```

Paste your example `Json` response to site , select source type  **JSON** , annotation : **Gson**    : [Json Schema to Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

In your `build.gradle` : `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'`

Comment: awesome bro, very helpful. My other problem was `status` that was set to Transient (from previous version). I changed that and I parse server response now. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome, glad to fix your problem. Have a good day :)